# found 63 low severity vulnerabilities while installing npm depencies

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

pm WARN ts-pnp@1.0.1 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: What have you done? What is the problem you've experienced? It seems to be impossible to understand either of these points from the current state of question.

Comment: Could you be more specific with the question here? What are you trying to solve? are the dependencies not installed? Are you asking why you received that message? Are you asking how to solve the low vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `npm audit fix` to resolve the vulnerabilities.

I think you still get the warning about typescript, but if you are not using that then no matter.